# Automorphisms and Definable subsets?

Tags: logic, model-theory

I'm trying to show that if we have a structure $\textbf{A}$ and $C\subseteq A$, with an $\mathcal{L}_C$ formula $\varphi(x)$ defining the set $S$ in $\textbf{A}$, then for any given automorphism  $h\in Aut(\textbf{A})$, we have the $\mathcal{L}_{h(c)}$ formula $h(\varphi)(x)$ defining the set $h(S)$.

The proof seems rather straightforward. By assumption, we have $\textbf{A}\vDash\varphi(\textbf{a})$, for each $a\in S$. So since $h$ is iso we have $\textbf{A}\vDash h(\varphi)(\textbf{h(a)})$ for each $h(a)\in h(S)$. Now consider arbitrary $a\in A$ such that $\textbf{A}\vDash h(\varphi)(\textbf{a})$. Since each $a\in A$ is $h(a')$, for some $a'\in A$, we have $\textbf{A}\vDash h(\varphi)(\textbf{h(a')})$ and so $\textbf{A}\vDash\varphi(\textbf{a'})$. Thus $a'\in S$ and $a\in h(S)$.

While the above seems to get the job done, I can't help shake the feeling I've done something illicit. Any help either confirming that I've got it or pointing out where I went wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: $\mathcal{L}_C$ is, what, $\mathcal{L}$ with a predicate for $C$? $\mathcal{L}$ with names for every member of $C$?

Comment: The second: Names for every element of $C$

Comment: Ohh. Then how are you guaranteed that there are names $\mathbf{a}$ for each $a\in S$? unless you require $S\subseteq C$. But it doesn't seem that anything about $\varphi(x)$ ensures that the $S$ it defines satisfies that.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean: $\varphi(\textbf{a})$ is an $\mathcal{L}_A$ formula, which is an expansion of $\mathcal{L}_C$, so it should be fine.

Comment: Not to worry, then. I was wondering if that got in the way. Your definition of $\models$ uses names for anything in the model, as needed.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Does that mean that the above goes through? I'm still suspicious of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31279/discussion-between-briano-and-e-boone).